# Symfony - finding last created entity

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-3.4

I want to find last created user from my db table.

Is this the best way or should I use QueryBuilder for that?

```
public function findLastCreatedUser()
{
    return $this->getUserRepository()->findOneBy([], [
        'id' => 'DESC'
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fine way to do it! If you don't need to change the query depending on a set of parameters this is probably the best choice.